# Java.mail timing out when called too frequently

Tags: java, email, servlets

I'm writing a servlet that sends confirmation emails.

Generally, it works fine, but if I call it a couple of times quickly (with delays of < 1 seconds) it starts to fail by hanging on Transport.send or it throws the error "Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.[domain].org, port: 25" and the stack trace explains it timed out. I initially thought this was a threading issue, but it happens even if I just loop calls on a thread with a short delay between them. I'm using an established ISP for the mail server, so it seems like it should be able to handle more than 1 request/second. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
private void sendConfirmationEmail (String email, String invitationID){

    log.info("sendConfirmationEmail called");

    String body = "Sample email sent to " + email;

    initSession();

    try {

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mySession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM, "Test account"));

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        message.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        message.setText(body);

        log.info("about to send over transport for " + email);
        Transport.send(message);
        log.info("Email sent");

    }
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not send confirmation email: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Unsupported Encoding");
    }
}
```

I'm initializing session as a static variable with this code:

```
public static void initSession () {
    if (mySession == null){

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        mySession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: It's highly likely that it's the server that causing the issue.  I'd have to believe that any mail server worth it's weight would prevent clients from flooding it with requests repeatedly.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out the server was being shared between users and queueing requests after a certain point, but the call was still timing out even though the messages were getting received appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting up the property connectiontimeout and timeout during initialising

```
public static void initSession () {
  if (mySession == null){

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 1200);
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 1000);

    mySession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
            }
        });

}
```

}